# Flutter - Dart: how to return a Text widget from my function correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

so my problem is that I'm trying to load a screen after logging in with an user (firebase auth), this works fine. When logged in, I'm matching the users id from firebase auth, with the same id in firebase cloud, such that I can retrieve the data field "work_title" and display it directly in a Text widget.

So of what i can read off the internet, supposedly everything in the screen is drawn first, only then its possible to retrieve the auth id of the current user, thats why I'm using a futurebuilder.

My question now: why can't I return the `return Text(sh.data['work_title'].toString());`-part ? I do enter this part of the code, however it only returns the `return Text("??");`-part.

I've also attached an image of this.

Thanks :)

```
 Widget buildText2() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Loading ..."),
            );
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.hasData); // prints true, so we enter this part:
              DocumentReference doc = Firestore.instance
                  .collection("user_profiles")
                  .document(snapshot.data.uid);
              doc.get().then((sh) {
                if (sh.exists) {
                  print(sh.exists); // prints true, så vi enter here as well:
                  print(sh.data['work_title'].toString());
                  return Text(sh.data['work_title'].toString()); // <-- I want to return this
                }
              });
            }
          } return Text("??");
        });
  }
```

[A screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbilJ.png)

Comment: Did you try using `Center(child: Text(sh.data['work_title'].toString()))` instead of using Text

Comment: yes, just tried it - doesnt change a thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following (unfortunately i cannot test it..):

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
     if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
       return Center(child: Text("Loading ..."));
     } else {
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
         print(snapshot.hasData); // prints true, so we enter this part:
         DocumentReference doc = Firestore.instance
           .collection("user_profiles")
           .document(snapshot.data.uid);
         return FutureBuilder(
           future: doc.get(),
           builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.hasData) {
               if (snapshot.data.exists) {
                 return Text(snapshot.data.data['work_title'].toString()); // <-- I want to return this
               } else {
                 return Text('sh does not exists..');
               }
             } else {
               return Text('Still Loading...');
             }
            },
           );
          }
         }
       return Text("??");
})
```

Comment: Just tried your code, now it doesnt return anything at all

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.. it was only an untested guess... i thought the problem might be the timing.. namely that doc.get() returns a promise instead of a widget (as you can see the IDE complains about a similar problem..). I thought it might be solved with another futurebuilder..

Comment: My bad - you are actually right! Must have copy/pasted something in wrong. It works now